# CSS Grid is being overwritten and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a 4 x 4 grid of 16 squares(divs). I have made the container div with a grid display. The 16 squares are in rows but when I try to make 4 columns it has a strikethrough in the styles tab of the dev tools.

Here is what I have in my CSS:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: none;
}

#heading{
    height: 250px;
}


#wrapper{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#container{
    border: solid 1px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25%, 25%, 25%, 25%;
    height: 600px;
    width: auto;
}

.squares{
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

They 16 child divs are created with JS. Would that have an impact on why grid is not working as expected?

```
let x = 0;

do{
    const square = document.createElement("div");
square.className = "squares";
square.setAttribute("id","block");
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(square);
    x++;
}
while(x < 16);
```

Comment: Would be nice if you could also share your html code.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `,` between the `grid-template-columns` values.
You can also change it to `auto` instead of doing the calculation yourself if they are all the same and specify `25%`.
take a look now

```js
let x = 0;

do{
    const square = document.createElement("div");
square.className = "squares";
square.setAttribute("id","block");
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(square);
    x++;
}
while(x < 16);
```

```css
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: none;
}

#heading{
    height: 250px;
}


#wrapper{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#container{
    border: solid 1px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    height: 600px;
    width: auto;
}

.squares{
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: @bmcginnis007 did you get the answer you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

The commas are interfering with the `grid-template-columns`, if you do:

```
 grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
```

should fix the mentioned issue